# @AuditJoinTable not working while auditing the many to many relations using Hibernate envers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and Spring Data JPA 1.9.4 with MS Sql server2014 database for process for process of mapping a many-to-many relationship.

I have two tables with entities Book & Publisher. where they have many to many relations ship with BookPublisher table and BookPublisher entity.

I used hibernate envers 4.3.3 final to audit the each entity. Book_AUD and Publisher_AUD and BookPublisher_AUD tables created automatially  by placing the @Audited annotation on each entity.

Book_AUD and Publisher_AUD are working properly to audit the inserting, updating and deleting.

Record is getting saved to join table when save the record in Book table with set of publisher records. But auditing happen only in inserting BookPublisher_AUD table, not in updating the deleting.

I used @AuditJoinTable annotation to audit the relation mapping table as below.

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "BookPublisher", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BookId", referencedColumnName = "BookId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PublisherId ", referencedColumnName = "PublisherId"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "isActive = 1 ")
    @AuditJoinTable
    private Set<Publisher> publishers;
```

Is there any way to audit the relational mapping table  in hibernate envers or any wrong in using @AuditJoinTable annotation?

Comment: First off, `@AuditJoinTable` should only be used if you want to give the join table a specific name, otherwise it does nothing, envers already knows what to do with a `@JoinTable`. I don't really understand how you define failure of auditing, can you post examples of the data in your tables? your hibernate configurations? any envers default properties changed?

Comment: I am very much new to the hibernate envers, so i just added the @Audited annotation to Book and publisher entity to audit but not to BookPublisher entity.  I removed the AuditJoinTable annotation in collection mapping element in Book entity but no use.  I added only three properties in my application properties file as below   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=Audit
Still i auditing not working to capture the updating and deleting records. So can you please give sample example code to prove solution.

Comment: I did code changes , now auditing happen only in inserting & deleteing the collection publisher object  from Book entity via Book repository. Is there any limitation in hibernate envers to not support directly interact the BookPublisher repository?

Comment: @SatishKonda hello, I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution on this?